# Why youtube compression algorithm doesn't work well for Minecraft videos?

Tags: youtube, compression

Minecraft videos have very small entropy : I can play hours to minecraft online exchanging only tens or hundred MB of data with the server, this is an entropy upper bound for Minecraft videos. However, Minecraft videos are quite large : one hour video is at least 1 GB.

[Turbo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code), for instance, should allow to be very close to the entropy. So, why youtube compression algorithm doesn't work well for Minecraft videos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft is a game written in Java that renders arrangements of blocks. Storing the parameters necessary to define an arrangement of unrendered blocks in Minecraft requires a lot less storage space than the way YouTube does it by starting with a video of rendered arrangements of blocks and then using a compression algorithm to make the video file smaller and suitable for playing in YouTube.

I suppose that from an information theory perspective you would be interested in working backwards from the YouTube video and trying to programmatically extract the parameters necessary to define the arrangements of blocks in Minecraft from it. I don't believe that this is possible, and the reason why is that if it was possible then it would also be possible to start with an out of focus cell phone photo of the image displayed on a computer screen and then programmatically reconstruct an accurate screenshot from it. For example, if the computer program could identify that the captured screen image was from Windows, it could search through a large library of Windows screenshots for matching images. I understand that it is sometimes possible to extract the numbers on a license plate from a blurry low resolution photograph using optical character recognition software.

In addition to the aforementioned, YouTube uses a "lazy eye" compression algorithm that ignores a lot of the visual redundancy in a video that can be perceived by careful observation.

Comment: Why youtube doesn't use a better compression algorithm ?

Comment: One reason for YouTube not using better compression algorithms developed by Google which are currently available is so that YouTube will be more stable on less powerful hardware.

Comment: If I recall correctly at least some of the downvotes were downoted when your question was originally asked at Web Applications before it was migrated to Superuser because at least half of the question was considered to be off topic there. Web Applications is not a large website, but it is an advanced website and even the professional programmers at Stack Overflow could learn from them. What you regard as condemnation helps the users at Web Applications to get better answers in the long run, even though it is not a relevant point now that your question has been migrated here.